# match_phrase query on concatenated fields -- avoid false matches

Tags: elasticsearch, stop-words, full-text-indexing

I index quite a complex document that does not have all the fields defined in a template (they are auto-created). I also populate a field that is the result of concatenating all string fields in the document separated by spaces (before it is loaded), except a few certain fields. This field is used as the "whole document" search field, and is indexed is several different ways using sub-fields.

For the most part it works well, except I notice I sometimes get "false" matches on phrase queries where a phrase matches the end of one field and the beginning of another, as they were concatenated is such a way to make this possible.

To prevent this from happening, I am thinking of separating all the fields in the concatenation with a dummy word, like MYSEP, and then making that word a stop-word in the index, but NOT in the query. No match can ever occur then. However having to maintain different lists of stop-words and different index/query analysers is a pain, so I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve the same.

Is there any way to tell ElasticSearch that a phrase match should not cross some boundary defined by some word or character within a string?

Comment: I pretty much see what you're trying to do (although a small example would probably help). A few questions: 1) Why would you need different separators? 2) Why do you need to concatenate all data into your custom "all" field instead of querying fields separately (because of free text search and you have no idea where to search)? 3) Do you rely heavily on scoring to show your results?

Comment: 1) im not sure what you are referring to
2) there are hundreds of potential fields that I dont control, and there is no template defined for them, and new ones comes often
3) across documents yes, but not between fields

Comment: 1) you mentioned "having to maintain different lists of stop-words and different index/query analysers is a pain", hence my question: "why different separators"? 2) Then if you don't/can't control your mapping, you should really pay attention to mapping explosion

Comment: 3) If you're using the scoring, you should really pay attention to how you're concatenating those field values because that heavily influences how the scoring is computed. In other words, the score of a matching document based on the concatenated field can be much different (higher or lower) than the score of the same document if the query was made directly on the relevant field.

Comment: 1) the different list of stop words is to allow for the separator to work in the first place (as it needs to be removed from index but present in query) 2) yes that is something we need to be watchful for 3) our kind of queries are usually for fairly unique words that in combination with other words typically result in a handful of documents, so it works well enough

Comment: At this point, I think it would help if you could provide some tangible data (sample mapping, sample document, sample query, expectations, etc)